# Automation studio project not build

Tags: br-automation-studio

The project is not going to be installed in AS 4.3 (this version is needed), the transfer button is not lit during assembly, the same problem was on 4.2 and 3.0, what could be the matter?[Don't build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I0gw.jpg)

It runs on a virtual machine, but I don't have version 4.3 on it.